# Formatting "2011-2012 Q1" as "Q1 11-12" in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Basically my table contains a fiscal year field that looks like "2011-2012 Q1" and I want to output that as "Q1 11-12" using SQL only if possible. This is for an ASP.NET page if that helps.

Comment: when you say 'fiscal year field' do you mean string field with the text "2011-2012 Q1"?

Comment: 1. Do this in your web page code 2. Fix how you store the data (example FiscalYearEnding, Quarter)

Comment: @Sam Holder: Yes it is a string field with text.

Comment: +1 for @gbn.  this is much more efficient to do in the web page code I would say and you should have a better system than storing a string you need to munge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about;

```
;with test (fiscal) as (
    select  '2011-2012 Q1' union
    select  '1990-1991 Q2' union
    select  '2012-2013 Q4' union
    select  '1999-1999 Q3'  
)
select
    right(fiscal, 2) + ' '
    +
    substring(fiscal, 3, 2) + '-'
    +
    substring(fiscal, 8, 2)
from test


>>Q2 90-91
>>Q3 99-99
>>Q1 11-12
>>Q4 12-13
```

Comment: Perfect, works great from me with little manipulation.  
  
    SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(Quarter, 2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(Quarter, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(Quarter, 10, 2) AS Qrtr  
    FROM            quartersSource  
    ORDER BY Qrtr DESC

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @s varchar(20)
set @s = '2011-2012 Q1'
select right(@s, 2) + ' ' + substring(@s, 3, 3) + substring(@s, 8, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way but you **could** use this

```
PRINT RIGHT('2011-2012 Q1', 2) + ' ' + RIGHT(LEFT('2011-2012 Q1', 4), 2) + '-' + RIGHT(LEFT('2011-2012 Q1', 9), 2)
```

which returns

```
Q1 11-12
```

Please note that SQL Server is not really designed for string manipulation and I would encourage you to put the display logic where it really belongs - in you UI

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT(col, 2) +' '+ SUBSTRING(STUFF(col, 6,2,''), 3,5)
FROM (SELECT '2011-2012 Q1' col) t
```